# Nested CMakeLists.txt files in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Using CLion, I have a project structure that looks like this:

[image]

You'll see that in the root there are an `include` directory, a `src` directory, a `lib` directory, a `cmake-build-debug` directory, a `CMakeLists.txt` file (see red arrow), and a `tests` directory. The project builds a shared object into `lib` using the root-level `CMakeLists.txt` file and the various source, header, and external files.

I can successfully run the root-level `CMakeList.txt` file and build the library. So far, so good.

Here is the issue. In addition to the above, I am now interested -- on an informal, exploratory basis -- in testing some of the code in the project. To that end, as an initial example, I have created a `test_nnls` directory with its own `CMakeLists.txt` (see yellow arrow) file and a `test_nnls.cpp` file. The code in `test_nnls.cpp` creates some dummy data, calls a function in `src/nnls.cpp`, and prints the results. The build process here just creates an executable that does this. This approach is not meant to be part of any formal test framework and I do not want the test to run as part of the root-level build. This is just me adding a simple test program in the overall project that I would like to compile and run on an independent basis when I feel the need. I plan to possibly implement a formal test framework later, but at present I don't know how to do this and for now just need to print some simple output to see if the chosen code is working correctly.

The problem is that I cannot seem to execute the `CMakeLists.txt` file (yellow arrow) to build the test. It does not appear to be possible in CLion to set up a build for the test program using `cmake`. How do I structure all of this to get what I want? Thanks.

Comment: Include the tests from your root CMakeLists.txt, then exclude your test programs from the main build either by adding `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to the `add_subdirectory` call OR hiding everything behind an `if (TESTING)` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't execute a `CMakeLists.txt`. It is read by `cmake` (the root `CMaksLists.txt` file), which is called by CLion. However, CLion only passes the root `CMaksLists.txt` file to `cmake`. Even if you call cmake yourself you would only pass this root `CMaksLists.txt` file.

If you want to define targets (or anything) in other `CMaksLists.txt` files located in other folders, then you must add `add_subdirectory(folder_name_that_contains_another_CMakeLists_file)` to your root `CMaksLists.txt` file. Only then targets in these other `CMaksLists.txt` files will appear in CLion.

Note that a few things should appear in the root `CMaksLists.txt` file, but not in the other ones. Particularly, the two lines below should only be in the root file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)  # Choose the minimum cmake version
project(name_of_your_project)
```

Comment: Once I have added the two lines you suggested in the root-level `CMakeLists.txt` file and CLion has created a separate target entry for the target in the lower level `CMakeLists.txt`, does this mean that I can somehow tell CLion/`cmake` to follow only the instructions in the lower level file? I didn't want to run the root-level instructions.

Comment: I am beginning to wonder whether, given my interest in separating the running of instructions in the root-level file from those in the lower file, I would be better off moving the test code and corresponding `CMakeLists.txt` file to another project/directory.

Comment: Braking the configuration into multiple `CMakeLists.txt` files is more a matter of organization. Everything is **a single project** and that is why only the root `CMakeLists.txt` file should have these lines. What is the benefit of having the test code in a different project? You can choose exactly which target you want to compile and run n CLion. If you care about the target `all` and you would not like the tests target to be include in it the target `all`, then just add `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` to the tests target as in @Botje's comment.

Comment: Actually, after some more fiddling around, I am now able to make everything work as hoped. I've kept the tests in the same project. Thanks.

Comment: If you think this answer fully answers your question then you can accept it. Unless there is something more. In that case you can comment here such that either me or something else can answer.